# Никак не могу запустить turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Помогите, пожалуйста, с ребенком разбираемся в коде, в котором необходимо нарисовать робота.
Рисуем ступни, а получается просто прямая линия.

```
import turtle as t
def rectangle(horizontal, vertical, color):
    t.pendown()
    t.pensize(l)
    t.color(red)
    t.begin_fill()
    for counter in range(l, 3):
        t.forward()
        t.right(90)
        t.forward()
        t.right(90)
    t.shape('turtle')
    t.setheading(0)
    t.forward(80)
    t.penap()
    t.speed('slow')
    t.bgcolor('Doodger blue')
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
#ступни
t.goto(-100, -150)
rectangle(50, 20, 'blue')
t.goto(-30, -150)
rectangle(50, 20, 'blue')
#ноги
t.goto(-25, -50)
rectangle(15, 100, 'grey')
t.goto(-55, -50)
rectangle(-15, 100, 'grey')

t.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Что за `penap` ещё, много непонятного )

Answer (score 3):

Главными ошибками у вас являются:

- Применение **буквы** `l` (строчное **L**) вместо **числа** `1` (один) и наоборот. Да, они выглядят одинаково, но для компьютера они являются совсем разными символами.
  (Строки **4** и **7** вашего кода.)
- **Отсутствие апострофов** там, где вы хотите задать **буквальный** текст (`red` вместо правильного `'red'`).
  (Строка **5** вашего кода.)
- **Отсутствие параметра** (т.е. уточнения действия в скобках за его именем) там, где это уточнение **строго требуется** (`t.forward()` - нужно задать длину перемещения, например  `t.forward(8)` или `t.forward(horizontal)`).
  (Строки **8** и **10** вашего кода.)
- **Опечатки** (компьютер — в отличие от человека — опечатки не понимает) (`penap` вместо правильного `penup` —  да, оно произносится как «penap» —  и 'Doodger blue' вместо правильного `'Dodgerblue'`, с одним `o` и без пробела — да, правильно по-английски с пробелом, но **имина цветов** для компьютера пишутся всегда как **одно слово**, без пробелов).
  (Строки **15** и **17** вашего кода.)

Answer (score 1):

Убрал необъявленные переменные, добавил использование нужных, ещё что-то.

Старайтесь добиваться от ребёнка, чтобы понимал каждое действие. Например, было откуда-то скопировано `t.pensize(l)`, а переменной `l` у вас вовсе нет. Или `t.forward()`  - означает двигаться вперед на длину, указанную в скобках, а в скобках ничего не указано.

Спросите, почему я вставил `t.penup()` перед каждым `goto` ?
Почему переписал цикл рисования прямоугольника таким образом?

Сделайте сами небольшое исправление, чтобы прямоугольники рисовались цветом `color`, указанным при вызове функции, а не красным.

И пишите программу по небольшим частям.

```
import turtle as t

def rectangle(horizontal, vertical, color):
    t.pendown()
    t.pensize(1)
    t.color("red")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.shape('turtle')
    t.setheading(0)
    t.speed('slow')
    for counter in range(2):
        t.forward(horizontal)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(vertical)
        t.right(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()

#ступни
t.bgcolor('light blue')
t.penup()
t.goto(-100, -150)
rectangle(50, 20, 'blue')
t.penup()
t.goto(-30, -150)
rectangle(50, 20, 'blue')
#ноги
t.penup()
t.goto(-25, -50)
rectangle(15, 100, 'grey')
t.penup()
t.goto(-55, -50)
rectangle(-15, 100, 'grey')
t.shape('classic')
t.goto(0, 0)
t.exitonclick()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]